# issue with css dropdown menu third level

Tags: drop-down-menu

i have dropdown menu with second level
  here is my code
  how can i change my code to 3level menu ?
  my languge is right to left
  i'm trying to add 3 level but it show under second level 
  what i need to add for 3 level?

```
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">home</a></li>

                <li><a href="help.php">help</a></li>

                <li><a href="help.php">visa</a>
                              <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Cozy Couch</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Great Table</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">3rd</a><ul><li><a href="#">test 3rd</a></li></ul></li>
                             </ul>

                </li>

                 <li><a href="faq.php">faq</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact-us.php">contact us</a></li>


            </ul>
        </div>
```

and it;s css code

```
.menu
{
    width:1000px;
    height:40px;

    direction:rtl;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-top:7px;
}

.menu ul
{
      margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float:right;
    font-family:tahoma;
    font-size:11px;
}

.menu ul li
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: right;

}
.menu li ul {
    display: none;
        float:right;
}
.menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;

    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;

    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.menu ul li a:hover {
background: #3b3b3b;
}
.menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

    .menu li:hover li {
        float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.menu li:hover a { background: #3b3b3b; }
.menu li:hover li a:hover {
    background: #1e7c9a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to position the third level relative to the second level and set the `top` and `left` CSS properties.

Alternately, these days, multi-leveled menus are somewhat frowned upon. They're hard to use, especially for mobile/touchscreen users (not saying impossible to do correctly, but hard). I believe the preferred solution these days are mega-menus, which convey more information, but are still tucked away to be called upon when needed.

If not a selected answer, I hope you at least find the suggestions helpful.